# Using .htaccess to remove PHP parameters from URL(without reloading the page)

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to work out how to remove the $_GET parameters from a URL.

I am using PHP to switch content so I can use one page(index.php).

An example URL is: www.example.com/?page=test OR www.example.com/index.php?page=test

I want it so if anything after and including the ? is removed.

So the result will always show: www.example.com/ OR www.example.com

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=test$
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ $0? [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, it seams to just load the index page and the query is still in the URL, I want the URL to be clean, no queries, for all queries, can you explain what everything means also please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is a `?` in `$0?` which will strip off any query in the rewritten page. You asked for **without reloading the page** that's why URL in browser is still showing query string but internally there is none.

Comment: Same Problem?(reference purposes) I found a way around this by creating "virtual" directories using .htaccess for specific parameters like: www.example.com/folder/ is recognized as www.example.com/index.php?page=folder (Google: .htaccess virtual directory), and thanks for your help anubhava.

Comment: If things work out for you then you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on top left of this answer.